# Proper syntax for exec of SQL Server stored procedure from within Excel 2007

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

Let's skip to the command text box on the definitions tab of the connection properties.... my command type is SQL.

I can execute `spDuplicatesAnalysis` from within SSMS. I have tried a numbee things with no luck, including ...

```
exec spDuplicatesAnalysis
dbo.spDuplicatesAnalysis
```

So how should the actual command txt read ?

Thx!

Comment: Have you been through the guide here? http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2010/06/07/running-a-sql-stored-procedure-from-excel-no-vba.aspx

Comment: This is really spotty, so I'm not putting it as an answer, but I have sometimes tricked Excel into calling stored procedures by (1) going into Microsoft Query, (2) editing the sql manually, and (3) enclosing the exec command in { } brackets.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/325163/how-to-execute-a-stored-sql-procedure-in-microsoft-excel

Answer (score 0):

**Calling stored procedures from Excel VBA**

1. Open a new Excel workbook
2. Name one of the tabs "Data" (or change the code below)
3. Open the VB Editor (Alt+F11)
4. Add a new module
5. Set a reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects (choose highest version number available)
   [image: Setting Reference to Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects]
6. Add the following code to your module

   ```
   Sub ExecStoredProcedureFromExcelVBA()

   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim connectString As String
   Dim custState As String
   Dim tgt As Worksheet

   Set tgt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
   custState = "TX"

   ' Clear the target worksheet
   tgt.UsedRange.Clear

   ' Set the connection string
           connectString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=.;" & _
                " Initial Catalog=Sandbox;Integrated Security = SSPI"

   ' Create the adodb objects
   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

   ' Open the connection and execute the stored procedure
   cn.Open connectString
   cn.spGetCustomersForState custState, rs

   ' Check for results
   If rs.state = 1 Then
       If Not rs.EOF Then
           ' Write the contents of the recordset to our target
           tgt.Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset rs
       rs.Close
       End If
   End If

   ' Clean up after ourselves
   If CBool(cn.state And adStateOpen) Then cn.Close
   Set cn = Nothing
   Set rs = Nothing

   End Sub
   ```
7. Modify the module to reference the database, stored procedure, and parameters you want to work with
8. Run the code